# Use vi to edit a file got black screen when connected to redhat server via ssh in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, ssh, vpn, vi

After using forticlient to connect to Linux server (redhat 7.9), I connected to the Linux server with "ssh @".   Then I try to edit a text file with vi after login.  But I got a black screen.  vi can accept commands (e.g. :q) but the screen is all black.   I need to use putty to connect to the linux server and then use vi to edit the file.

Can anybody help?  many thx.